# Unable to access properties of a nested event object - Fullcalendar jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

Using the fullcalendar jquery plugin with a laravel backend.  I am unable to iterate and display all values of the property[leader] of the nested object below. When I iterate over that property[leader], I am only able to display a single value.  How can I iterate over the nested object and display all its values as an event on FullCalendar?

```
//event object
$event_obj = [  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "description":"A description",
      "date":"2018-08-28",
      "start_time":"10:00:00",
      "end_time":"12:00:00",
      "event_color":"#ffff00",
       "location":[  
         {  
            "name":"Foo1"
         },
         {  
            "name":"Foo2"
         }
      ],
      "leader":[  
         {  
            "name":"Foo bar1"
         },
         {  
            "name":"Foo bar2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                 header: {
                     left: 'prev,next',
                     center: 'title',
                     right: 'month,agendaWeek'

                 },
                 firstDay: 1,
                 theme: true,



                 events : [
                @foreach($event_obj as $ev_obj)
                {
                    title : '{{ $ev_obj->location->name }}',
                    start : new Date('{{ $ev_obj->date }}T{{ $ev_obj->start_time }}') ,

                    color : ' {{ $ev_obj->event_color }}',


                    @if( !empty($event_obj->leader))
                     @foreach ($event_obj->leader as $key => $leader )

                    name_leader: '{{ $leader }}' ,
                     @endforeach
                    @endif

                },
                @endforeach
            ],

            eventRender: function(event, element) {

             element.find('.fc-title').append('<div class="hr-line-solid-no-margin"></div><span style="font-size: 10px">'+event.name_leader+'</span></div>');
              }
              })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you define the `name_leader:` property twice in your JS event object. Due to the `@foreach ($event_obj->leader as $key => $leader )` loop you'll end up with an object like

```
{ 
  "title": "A description", 
  "start": "2018-08-28T10:00:00", 
  "color": "#ffff00",
  "name_leader": "Foo bar1",
  "name_leader": "Foo bar2",
}
```

Notice there are two "name_leader" properties.

Now, in `eventRender`, when you write `event.name_leader`...how is the computer supposed to know which of the two identically-named properties you intended to use? Clearly it cannot decide. Your object is not valid.

Since "leaders" in your PHP object is an array, in your JS it must also be an array.

I think this will sort it. In your event object:

```
leader: [
@if( !empty($event_obj->leader))
  @foreach ($event_obj->leader as $key => $leader )
    { name: '{{ $leader }}' },
  @endforeach
@endif
]
```

In eventRender:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
  if (event.leader.length > 0)
  {
    var html = '<div class="hr-line-solid-no-margin"></div><span style="font-size: 10px">';
    for (var i = 0; i < event.leader.length; i++ )
    {
      html += (i > 0 ? ", " : "") + event.leader[i].name + ;
    }
    html += '</span></div>';
  }
  element.find('.fc-title').append(html);
}
```

P.S. You also have a logical problem with `$ev_obj->location->name` - `location` is a list, so it won't directly have a "name" property. I'd expect you'd need to write $ev_obj->location[0]->name` for this to work.

---

To be honest though, unless your PHP/Laravel event data is already being used for something else, I don't know why you don't just make that data be in the right format for fullCalendar to begin with. It's not far away from it. Then you don't have to mess about transposing it.

If you made your event object like this:

```
$event_obj = [  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "title":"Foo1",
      "description":"A description"
      "start":"2018-08-28T10:00:00",
      "end":"2018-08-28T12:00:00",
      "color":"#ffff00",
      "location":[  
        {  
          "name":"Foo1"
        },
        {  
          "name":"Foo2"
        }
      ],
      "leader":[  
         {  
           "name":"Foo bar1"
         },
         {  
           "name":"Foo bar2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Then in your JS code you could just do this (or similar, I'm not familiar with the specifics of Laravel's template syntax, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
events : @{{ json_encode($event_obj); }}
```

and then also modify `eventRender` as I showed above.